# Locally using git between users on the same server

Tags: git

Is there a way to set up a local git repository that would be accessed by users on the same server, such that providing ssh public/private keys and connecting to another server to access the repository is not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git can use file:// URLs. The second user will need to clone the repo into it's own directory and then may commit back to the original.

```
git clone file:///home/user1/repo
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Don't forget that you can't push to checked-out repos, so your users will have to issue pull requests to each other by some external (non-git) means.

Comment: Or alternatively set up a third, *bare*, repository that acts as the central “meeting point” for your repositories.